# COBOL Sort and Merge Concurrently

Tags: cobol

I am having a very difficult time with an assignment I have been given. I am to sort and merge two txt files filled with stock data. I am then to prompt the user to enter a year and the master record will print the records that are within that year. Can anyone please help me. This is what I currently have.

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.

       SELECT STOCK-REPORT-A ASSIGN TO 'PR3AF11.TXT'.

       SELECT STOCK-REPORT-B ASSIGN TO 'PR3BF11.TXT'.

       SELECT MERGE-FILE ASSIGN TO 'WORK.TMP'.

       SELECT MASTER-STOCK-REPORT ASSIGN TO 'MASTERSTOCKREPORT.TXT'.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.

   FD  STOCK-REPORT-A.
   01  REPORTA-REC.
       05  A-InvestorID             PIC X(2).
       05  A-InvestorName           PIC X(5).
       05  A-InvestorRating         PIC X.

   FD  STOCK-REPORT-B.
   01  REPORTB-REC.
       05  B-InvestorID             PIC X(2).
       05  B-InvestorName           PIC X(5).
       05  B-InvestorRating         PIC X.

   SD  MERGE-FILE.
   01  MERGE-REC.
       05  M-InvestorID             PIC X(2).
       05  M-InvestorName           PIC X(5).
       05  M-InvestorRating         PIC X.

   SCREEN SECTION.
   01  TITLE SCREEN.
       05  BLANK SCREEN
           FOREGROUND-COLOR BLACK
           BACKGROUND-COLOR WHITE.
       05  LINE 4 COLUMN 15
           VALUE "STOCKS REPORT GENERATOR"
   01  YEAR-QUESTION-SCREEN.
       05  YEAR-ANSWERS.
           10  LINE 7 COLUMN 10
               VALUE "What year would you like to search for?".
           10  LINE 9 COLUMN 15
               VALUE "2005".
           10  LINE 9 COLUMN 15
               VALUE "2006".
           10  LINE 9 COLUMN 15
               VALUE "2007".
           10  LINE 9 COLUMN 15
               VALUE "2008".
           10  LINE 9 COLUMN 15
               VALUE "2009".
           10  LINE 9 COLUMN 15
               VALUE "2010".
           10  LINE 9 COLUMN 15
               VALUE "2011".

   FD MASTER-STOCK-REPORT.
   01 MASTER-REC                    PIC X(122).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN.
   BEGIN.
       MERGE MERGE-FILE
           ON ASCENDING KEY M-InvestorID
           USING STOCK-REPORT-A
               STOCK-REPORT-B
           GIVING MASTER-STOCK-REPORT.
       STOP RUN.
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to sort and merge via `DFSORT` in `JCL` then input that file to the COBOL program which takes the user input and provides necessary output. Sorting and merging inside program is slower than doing outside, of course obviously...

Comment: The question is not Tagged a Mainframe, and the reference to "txt files" probably indicates that it is not Mainframe, so a Mainframe solution is not useful for the actual question, but may be for others. Cobol SORT/MERGE on the Mainframe uses the installed Sort product anyway. It is perfectly possible, by keeping it simple, to get the same performance as an external Sort. However, people tend to, rather than designing a program, get to the stage of "if I do a SORT just now it'll do what I want" and then the process gets confused and complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples on how to sort and merge, just do it as a two step operation.

http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/examples/default.htm#Sort

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort *and* merge. You can SORT both files together, specifying the two input files on the USING phrase of the SORT verb.

If you are unsure that this will give you the correct results, you can experiment with SORT, SORT, MERGE and then compare the output file to the above. Or sit down with a piece of paper and a pencil and work it through.